# How can I write each process from multiprocessing to a separate csv file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing

I have several large txt files. Call them mytext01.txt, mytext02.txt, mytext03.txt (in reality there are many more than three). I want to create a separate dataframe for each file that counts occurrences of certain keywords and then write each dataframe to its own csv file. I'd like each txt file to be handled in one process using the multiprocessing library.

I have written code that I thought would do what I wanted, but the csv file never appeared (the code doesn't seem to be doing much of anything-the entire thing runs more quickly than it would normally take to just load a single file). Here is a simplified version of what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool
keywords=['dog','cat','fish']
def count_words(file_number):
    file=path+'mytext{}.txt'.format(file_number)
    with open(file, 'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        text = f.read()
    text=text.split(' ')
    words_dict=dict(zip(positive,[0 for i in words]))
    for word in words_dict.keys():
        words_dict[word]=text.count(word)
    words_df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(words_dict,orient='index')
    words_df.to_csv('word_counts{}.csv'.format(file_number))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(count_words, ['01','02','03'])
```

I'm not super familiar with using multiprocessing, so any idea of what I have done wrong would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` at the end?

Comment: have you also tried Pool(processes=3) etc?

Comment: @MEdwin Mr. Hawkeye ;)

Comment: Have you tried to read your `.txt` files with `pd.read_csv("my_text1.txt", sep=" ")`?

Comment: @rpanai my actual files are json files, so I used json.load() and then extracted the relevant text sections (I know the issue isn't with this since I've loaded the same files this way in other code). Is pd.read_csv faster than f.read()? I could in theory load them as text and use ast to convert to dict. what makes you think pd.read_csv would work better?

Comment: @MEdwin and crayxt  (can only tag one) I have it running now with both your suggestions implemented and it has been running for a while-which in this case is a good thing because it actually seems to be doing something :)

Comment: @jmh123 it's not just about speed is that it's easier to code. If your `df` has a row for every column you could use this `df.groupby("word").size().to_csv(f"word_count{file_number}.csv", index=False)` instead of your last 5 lines in `count_words`

Comment: @rpanai clever! I will try that thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience it's better to have a dedicated function for parallelization as

```py
import multiprocessing as mp


def parallelize(fun, vec, cores):
    with mp.Pool(cores) as p:
        res = p.map(fun, vec)
    return res
```

Now you just have to check if your function `count_words` works for a single `file_number` and you can use `parallelize`.